# node-slack outgoing web-hook is missing the trigger property

Tags: node.js, webhooks, slack-api, slack

My current hook that my application receives from slack looks like the following. Missing the trigger_word property.

```
{ 
    token: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    team_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    channel_id: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    channel_name: 'channel',
    timestamp: Invalid Date,
    user_id: 'XXXXXXX',
    user_name: 'user',
    text: 'massive string'
}
```

The text property can be extrapolated to figure what the trigger value but this seems like a bit of a hassle. How can I make it so that it has the trigger_word as shown in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks)?

Answer (score -1):

The `req.body` had all the properties, but the node-slack module parsed through the hook and filtered out some useful ones.